# Setting THREE.BasicLineMaterial opacity to 0 produces a dashed white and gray line

Tags: three.js

I am making a THREE.Line object like this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 0));
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:'red'}));
```

When I set the opacity to 0 I expect the line to not be rendered. However, the line is rendered as a dashed white and gray line.

I set the line's opacity like this:

```
line.material.opacity = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I set the opacity to 0 I expect the line to not be rendered.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.opacity), if `Material.transparent` is not set to `true`, the material will remain fully opaque. Try it with the below code.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 4;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0));
  var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 'red',
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.5 // changing this to zero will make the line invisible
  }))
  scene.add(line);
    
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
canvas {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.118.3/build/three.js"></script>
```